# PHP/MySQL Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This has probably been asked, but as I am a massive PHP/MySQL noob I really don't know what it is I am looking for. I am executing the following query:

```
SELECT shortlink_analytics.shortlink AS short, 
COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink) AS shortcount, 
(SELECT link FROM shortlinks WHERE shortlinks.shortlink = shortlink_analytics.shortlink)    AS shLink 
FROM shortlink_analytics JOIN shortlinks ON shortlink_analytics.shortlink =   shortlinks.shortlink 
GROUP BY shortlink_analytics.shortlink 
ORDER BY COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink) DESC LIMIT 10
```

This used to work, but having revisited it in the last week I noticed that the output, instead of working, showed the error of:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

After playing around with the code I have managed to find that the problem lies (I think!) in the area of (but I'm not quite sure):

```
GROUP BY shortlink_analytics.shortlink 
ORDER BY COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Would anyone be able to explain:

- where I have gone wrong?
- possible reason as to why it was working a month a go and then it stopped working?
- what would be the way to fix my problem?

Comment: Why not use an `INNER JOIN` to replace this part `SELECT link FROM shortlinks WHERE shortlinks.shortlink = shortlink_analytics.shortlink`. This make your query more readable and probably perform better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is the subquery:

`(SELECT link FROM shortlinks WHERE shortlinks.shortlink = shortlink_analytics.shortlink)`

Can you simply `LIMIT` it to 1 row?

`(SELECT link FROM shortlinks WHERE shortlinks.shortlink = shortlink_analytics.shortlink LIMIT 1)`

You should try to find out why your data is returning multiple rows, and you may even need to `ORDER BY` to be sure the correct row is returned.

Comment: Cheers, this fixed my issue. But would you be able to further expand on why this would have worked some weeks ago but then stopped?

Comment: @SamStreet . . . Because the data changed and duplicates have now appeared.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the links on the relationship, use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT shortlink_analytics.shortlink AS short, 
       COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink) AS shortcount, 
       group_concat(link) as shlinks
FROM shortlink_analytics JOIN
     shortlinks ON
     shortlink_analytics.shortlink = shortlinks.shortlink 
GROUP BY shortlink_analytics.shortlink 
ORDER BY COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink)
DESC LIMIT 10;
```

If this guess is wrong, and you need the subquery, you can still get all the links by doing the `group_concat()` in the subquery:

```
SELECT shortlink_analytics.shortlink AS short, 
       COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink) AS shortcount, 
       (SELECT group_concat(link)
        FROM shortlinks
        WHERE shortlinks.shortlink = shortlink_analytics.shortlink
       ) AS shLinks
FROM shortlink_analytics JOIN
     shortlinks
     ON shortlink_analytics.shortlink = shortlinks.shortlink 
GROUP BY shortlink_analytics.shortlink 
ORDER BY COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink) DESC
LIMIT 10
```